# Getting the last inserted messages from ajax chat

Tags: php, ajax, mysqli, chat

I'm building a chat application and having some issues. First of all I want the chat starts loading from database  once the the user logs in.

function that gets the whole chat from db which is called by ajax

```
function getChatData(){
    global $mysqli;
    //echo $lastinseted= $mysqli->insert_id();
    $sql = "SELECT `chat`.`message`,
        `users`. `username`,
        `chat`.`timestamp`
        from `chat` JOIN `users` ON (`chat`.`user_id`=`users`.`user_id`) 
        ORDER BY `chat`.`timestamp` DESC limit 15";
    try{
        if($stmt=$mysqli->prepare($sql)){
            echo returnJson($stmt);
            $stmt->close();
            $mysqli->close();
        }else{
            throw new Exception("An error occured while fetching record data");
        }
    }catch(Exception $e){
        log_error($e, $sql, null);
        echo 'fail';
    }
}
```

here is the callback function:

```
function getChatCallback(data){
    var h='';
    for(var i=0, l=data.length;i<l;i++){
        h+=data[i].username+' says: '+data[i].message+'<span style="color:gray"> at the time '+data[i].timestamp+'</span><br/>';
    }
    $('.messages').html(h);
    setTimeout(getChat,1500);
 }
```

this is the function that will insert the new messages to the database which is called once the user hits enter and it is called also by ajax call:

```
function putChatData($message,$room,$user_id){
    global $mysqli;
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `chat`
    (`message`,`timestamp`,`room`,`user_id`)
    VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
    $timestamp = gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s");


    try{
        if($stmt=$mysqli->prepare($sql)){
             $stmt->bind_param('ssii',$message,$timestamp,$room,$user_id);

            $stmt->execute();

            $stmt->close();
            $mysqli->close();

        }else{  
            throw new Exception("An error occured while fetching record data");
        }
    }catch(Exception $e){
        log_error($e, $sql, null);
        echo 'fail';
    }

}
```

the problem now is that I could insert the new messages to the db, but the first function the gets the chat, brings all that chat including the old ones before the user logs in.  I tried to use timestamp or the last insert id but didn't work with me.

Comment: I see nothing criminal if user gets the piece of previous conversation and knows the subject. is it so bad?

Comment: after the new message inserted, you need to call the getChatData() function for updated messages..

Comment: heximal,I just want the new user starts viewing the chat the time he logs in. Parasath, that getChatData is called every two seconds, so when the new message inserted  it should show up right away, which what is happening right now. thanks

Comment: I recently did a chat program. I started out with the same approach you are using, however, after some research switched to a long polling option (that is what facebook uses). I would definitely recommend moving that direction. But regardless I always sent the id of the last message. Why wouldn't that work for you?

Answer (score 0):

For this usecase you need to know the reg time and add a WHERE condition to your query

```
$sql = "SELECT `chat`.`message`,
    `users`. `username`,
    `chat`.`timestamp`
    from `chat` JOIN `users` ON (`chat`.`user_id`=`users`.`user_id`) 
    WHERE `chat`.`timestamp` > $userRegDate 
    ORDER BY `chat`.`timestamp` DESC limit 15";
```

Comment: the format of `$userRegDate`must be the same as the one in `chat.timestamp`. output the variable to check if that is true in your code.